# Can I enter the Netherlands with a refugee travel document or do I need a visa?

Tags: netherlands, south-africa, refugees, democratic-republic-congo

I'm a refugee holding a travel document issued by South Africa, I'm Congolese from Democratic Republic of the Congo. I want to visit Amsterdam; do I need a visa ?

Comment: Are you the one who asked [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85303/does-a-south-african-refugee-travel-document-holder-need-a-transit-visa-for-germ)? You're still not saying _which Congo_, without which there's not much point in declaring yourself to be "congolese".

Comment: Go to the [IATA Travel Center](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/NL-Netherlands-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) and enter the details of your document etc and you will find out accurately. It does appear you need a visa.

Answer (score 2):

According to [IATA Travel Center](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/NL-Netherlands-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm):

[image]

So the answer is **no**, you cannot enter visa-free. It should also be noted that South-Africans themselves are also ineligible for visa-free entry to the Schengen area.